# Can we know the background code associated with basic mathematica functions

Tags: performance-tuning, functions, implementation-details

I wanted to know how computers calculate basic functions like `Sqrt` so first I checked how humans do it I found that they use something called "Newton's method" that is basically a iterative method to find the root of a number.

that can be efficiently reproduced in Mathematica as:

```
SqRoot[x_, assump_, precision_] := N[Nest[(# + x/#)/2 &, assump, 21], precision]
```

`Timing` it for 2 gives:

```
In:= Timing[SqRoot[2, 1, 123]]
Out:= {1.75, 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702492}
```

`1.75 Seconds`

While using same precision with `Sqrt` gives:

```
In:=Timing[N[Sqrt[2], 123]]
Out:= {1.6237*10^-15,1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702492}
```

`1.6237*10^-15 Seconds`

Meaning Mathematica uses an entirely different operation to calculate the root of a number

Like this there are tons of elementary functions like `Factorial` `Abs` `Solve` `Sin` `Cos` which result in similar fast results as compared to slower human results using slower loops and iterative methods.

Where can we find a compendium of all the back code that supports these functions and makes them faster than actual procedure.

P.S. This is related only to Mathematica  based functions (not theoreticalcs.SE)

Comment: Different `Timing` does not mean that `Mathematica` uses an entirely different operation ! Functions like `Sqrt` are written in a compiled language (`C`), `Mathematica` is basically interpreted. You can look how it is evaluated e.g. `Trace[N[Nest[(2 + x/2)/2, 1, 21], 123]
 ]`

Comment: Its taking a really long time.....

Comment: Maybe because your `N[]` is outside as opposed to being within the `Nest[]`, and the rational numbers that get generated become more unwieldy.

Comment: Compare your code with `FixedPoint[(# + 2/#)/2 &, N[1, 123]] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @J.M. yours is Way better ! but what about how mathematica actually evaluates the `Sqrt` function and other functions

Comment: With the thing being closed-source, most of the built-in functions won't reveal their secrets. It is possible to tweak a few things to see the code within, but I'm not sure if the guys at Wolfram would allow that...

Comment: `It is possible to tweak a few things to see the code within`....like?

Comment: You might want to start with [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LowLevelSystemSpelunking.html)...

Comment: You may also want to look at the [notes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) on internal implementation, specifically the section on basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, having `N` outside of `Nest` is the cause of the problems.

```
ListLogPlot[{
  {#, Timing[N[Nest[(# + 2/#)/2 &, 1, #], 123];][[1]]} & /@ Range[22],
  {#, Timing[Nest[N[(# + 2/#)/2, 123] &, 1, #];][[1]]} & /@ Range[22]
 },  Frame -> True, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

gives

[image]

I suspect the difference is that in your code, Mathematica is performing symbolic algebra before getting a numerical answer. But, moving `N` inside allows Mathematica to perform the same calculation with something more akin to machine numbers, even though they are not exactly machine numbers due to the extreme precision asked for.

Comment: "something more akin to machine numbers" - let's just call them "inexact numbers". :) It is instructive to replace `Nest[]` with `NestList[]` and remove the `N[]`, just to see the digit growth in the numerators and denominators of the approximations.

Comment: @J.M. yes, "inexact numbers" is correct, yet I wanted to highlight the fact that the speed up is really due to using something that is more like the internal machine representation than what is produced in the OP's code.