# How to evaluate this indefinite integral $\csc(4x)\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I tried to integrate the following integral using `Integrate[Sin[x]Csc[4x],x]` and I am getting a strange result.
$$\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{2}}\left(-2 i \text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{\text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]-\left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right) \text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]}{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]-\text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]}\right]-2 i \text{ArcTan}\left[\frac{\text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]-\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) \text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]}{\left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right) \text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]-\text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]}\right]+2 \sqrt{2} \text{Log}\left[\text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]-\text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]\right]-2 \sqrt{2} \text{Log}\left[\text{Cos}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]+\text{Sin}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]\right]+2 \text{Log}\left[\sqrt{2}+2 \text{Sin}[x]\right]-\text{Log}\left[2-\sqrt{2} \text{Cos}[x]-\sqrt{2} \text{Sin}[x]\right]-\text{Log}\left[2+\sqrt{2} \text{Cos}[x]-\sqrt{2} \text{Sin}[x]\right]\right) $$

While [the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%5BD%5B%281/8%29*ln%28sin%28x%29-1%29%2b%281/4%29*sqrt%282%29*arctanh%28sin%28x%29*sqrt%282%29%29-%281/8%29*ln%281%2bsin%28x%29%29,x%5D%5D) is

`(1/8) Log[Sin[x] - 1] + (1/4) Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[Sin[x] Sqrt[2]] - (1/8) Log[1 + Sin[x]]`
$$\frac{\text{ArcTanh}\left[\sqrt{2} \text{Sin}[x]\right]}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{8} \text{Log}[-1+\text{Sin}[x]]-\frac{1}{8} \text{Log}[1+\text{Sin}[x]] $$

Why am I getting this strange result? Are those two answers equivalent? How to avoid such strange results?

Comment: if you compare, say `Integrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x], {x, 0, 1/2}]` and `NIntegrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x], {x, 0, 1/2}]` they seem to agree which is a good sign.

Comment: I didn't check, but I'm willing to bet 2 dollars that they're equivalent.

Comment: @yohbs Why do you think so?

Comment: @belisarius I thought so because I thought that the OP was comparing two outputs of MMA. Now that I see this is not the case, I withdraw my bet like a coward.

Comment: Your WAlpha has an `Atanh`, not an `Atan`

Comment: @belisarius sorry for that ... my mistake

Comment: @rm-rf no this is not typo issue, I wanted to ask how would I get that value out of the complicated answer MMA gives me.

Comment: There is one more error in the coefficient before the `atanh`. Please try to be more careful

Comment: Also, please type it in Mathematica syntax, to help us not to retype it

Comment: Just curious, how did you get to your second answer?

Answer (score 9):

> Why am I getting this strange result?

Mathematica's symbolic integration methods are more complicated that first-year calculus methods, and can turn out to involve complex-valued functions.  See for instance [How does Mathematica integrate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6811/how-does-mathematica-integrate)

> Are those two answers equivalent?

1. Yes-but.  The term `Log[-1+Sin[x]]`, which is equivalent to `Log[1-Sin[x]] + Pi I`, is an undefined real-valued function for almost all $x$ -- might want to use `Log[1-Sin[x]]` instead if you're looking for a standard real analysis function.  The term is fine as a complex-valued function.
2. Yes, they're equivalent.  From calculus we know that over an interval over which a function is continuous, any two antiderivatives differ by a constant, which in fact may be a complex number.  Over disjoint intervals, the constants may differ.  Your function $\sin x \csc 4x$ is continuous over intervals of the form ${n\pi \over 4}<x<{(n+1)\pi\over4}$. If you examine b.gatessucks' and Nasser M. Abbasi's plots you can see that the answers differ by constant throughout each such interval. (In fact, your integrand has a removable discontinuity at $n\pi$ and so the constant does not change at those values.)

> How to avoid such strange results?

1. Learn to love them, then they won't be strange. ;-)  Seriously, they usually work as is, although in this case, for instance, you have to use the real part to graph it.
2. Try simplifying the real part, which will always be an antiderivative if the integrand is real:

   ```
   i = Integrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x], x];
   FullSimplify[Re[i], x \[Element] Reals]
   (* 1/32 (-8 ArcTanh[Sin[x]] + Sqrt[2] (2 Log[(Sqrt[2] + 2 Sin[x])^2] + 
      Log[1/(4 (-2 + Cos[2 x] + 2 Sqrt[2] Sin[x])^2)]))*)
   ```

Comment: thanks for an instructive answer. Can your `FullSimplify[Re[i], x \[Element] Reals]` answer always be considered a good anti-derivative throughout  all values of `x`. If so why does mathematica and maple not pick up this solution rather than the complex one above?

Comment: You can assume `Re[i]` will always be a valid antiderivative if your integrand is real-valued.  I do not know that `FullSimplify` will always give a result you seek, though it should always give a correct one.  Many people are surprised when they first learn `Sin[x]^2`, `-Cos[x]^2`, and `-Cos[2x]/2` are all antiderivatives of `2 Sin[x] Cos[x]`.  Even in a simple integral, one can't say definitively which is the best, and all are right.  All one can expect is that Mathematica, Maple, etc. give correct answers, but not always the same answer.

Comment: This is a very cool idea, but it does not work on on all antidirivatives like an antiderivative of (1 + x^2)^2/((1 - x^2)*(1 - 6*x^2 + x^4)^(3/4)) see https://github.com/stblake/algebraic_integration/issues/2

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников First of all, the integrand is not real (everywhere). Second, I don't see what the desired result in the link is after a quick scan; I'm not sure it's worth reading carefully given my first observation. Third, computational simplification always has had, and likely always will have, limitations. What the user wants and what it gives are not always the same.

Comment: From Euler, D[] gives correct result (also, the Integral without I should not have I in the antiderivative, read it somewhere): -ArcTanh[
    2*x*(x^4 - 6*x^2 + 1)^(1/4)/(Sqrt[x^4 - 6*x^2 + 1] + x^2 + 1)] + 
  ArcTan[x/((x^4 - 6*x^2 + 1)^(1/4) + 1)] - 
  ArcTan[((x^4 - 6*x^2 + 1)^(1/4) - 1)/x]

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников OK, but I don't see how this answer applies to your example, since the integrand is not real. `Re[i]` is not an antiderivative of the integrand
.

Comment: That is not needed that it is strictly real, it only should not contain I inside and then you can get without I too. In fact the difference between those (expr1 is the result of Integrate and expr2 is the result above) is -I Pi/2, so a constant. Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Series[expr1 - expr2 // FullSimplify, {x, 0, 10}] // Simplify] // Normal

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников It is an explicitly stated hypothesis of this answer, "the integrand is real." I think it is obvious that this is a necessary condition for the method shown. It is no surprise it does not work in your example. Your example has an antiderivative with complex values (for some `x`) no matter what the constant of integration is, even if all the formal occurrences of `I` are eliminated. `Re[i]` never has complex values and so cannot be a global antiderivative; therefore it cannot be equivalent to your desired formula. My method must fail in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Just playing around, *Mathematica* gives the correct solution :

```
int2 = FullSimplify[Integrate[TrigExpand[Sin[x] Csc[4 x]], x]];

FullSimplify@D[TrigToExp[int2], x]
(* Csc[4 x] Sin[x] *)
```

The real part of the two solutions match but the imaginary parts do not :

```
check = 1/8 Log[Sin[x] - 1] - 1/8 Log[Sin[x] + 1] + Sqrt[2]/4 ArcTanh[Sqrt[2] Sin[x]];

FullSimplify@D[check - int2, x]
(* 0 *)
```

and

```
SeedRandom[6];
FullSimplify[check - int2 /. x -> RandomReal[]]
(* 2.77556*10^-17 + 0.670379 I *)

Plot[Im[int2 - check], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, 
   Ticks -> {{#, #} & /@ Range[-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2], Automatic}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], None}]
```

[image: Im]

Answer (score 4):

Taking derivatives of your "correct answer" and comparing with the integrand, shows they are not that equal:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While taking derivatives of Mma's result gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: what does that mean?? Is my "correct answer" not correct? please check the link I added up.

Comment: @experimentX  I think there is an 'Atanh[]` whose `h` is missing in your question

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my mistake in Question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer looks correct by comparing it to Maple's 16 (latest version).

The function (the answer) gives complex values at different `x`. A plot of the real part is an exact match. For the complex part there is constant piecewise shift and the Abs of the solutions also agree up to piecewise constant so the answer seems to be correct. The solution are plotted for `x=-10..10`

Here is Maple result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This answer was typed into Mathematica and compared it with Mathematica's `Integrate` answer:

```
maple=(1/4)Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[Sin[x] Sqrt[2]]-(1/8) Log[1 + Sin[x]] + (1/8) Log[Sin[x]- 1]
mma = Integrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x], x];
```

**plot the real part**

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[{maple, mma}]], {x, -10, 10},PlotLegends -> {"maple", "mma"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Plot the complex part**

```
Plot[Evaluate[Im[{maple, mma}]], {x, -10, 10},PlotLegends -> {"maple", "mma"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**plot the magnitude**

```
Plot[Evaluate[Abs[{maple, mma}]], {x, -10, 10},PlotLegends -> {"maple", "mma"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Letting `t = Tan[x/2]`, we can get a simpler result.

```
Integrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x] D[2 ArcTan[t], t] /. x -> 2 ArcTan[t] // TrigExpand, t] /.
  t -> Tan[x/2] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
FullSimplify[%, 0 < x < Pi/2]
D[%, x] // Simplify
```

> $\frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{2} \left(\log \left(\sqrt{2} \sin (x)+1\right)-\log \left(\sqrt{2} \sin (x)-1\right)\right)-4 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)$
>
> $\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\csc (x)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)$
>
> $\sin (x) \csc (4 x)$

Alternatively, letting `t = Sin[x]`

```
Integrate[Sin[x] Csc[4 x] D[ArcSin[t], t] /. x -> ArcSin[t] // TrigExpand, t] /.
   t -> Sin[x] // FullSimplify
```

> $\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sin (x)\right)-\tanh ^{-1}(\sin (x))\right)$

Answer (score 1):

One can instantly recognize that the integrand can be expressed in terms of the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html):

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{\sin 4x}\mathrm dx=\int\frac1{U_3(\cos x)}\mathrm dx$$

and thus, by letting $t=\cos x$,

```
FullSimplify[PowerExpand[(Integrate[-1/(Sqrt[1 - t^2] ChebyshevU[3, t]), t] /.
                          t -> Cos[x]) /. Sqrt[tmp_] :> Sqrt[TrigFactor[tmp]]]]
   (-Sqrt[2] Log[Sqrt[2] - 2 Cos[x]] + 2 Log[Cos[x]] - Sqrt[2] Log[Sqrt[2] + 2 Cos[x]] -
    2 Log[1 + Sin[x]] + Sqrt[2] (Log[2 - Sqrt[2] Cos[x] + Sqrt[2] Sin[x]] +
    Log[2 + Sqrt[2] Cos[x] + Sqrt[2] Sin[x]]))/8
```

Check by differentiating the result:

```
Simplify[D[%, x] == Sin[x] Csc[4 x]]
   True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr0 = Sin[x] Csc[4 x];

expr1 = Integrate[expr0, x] // FullSimplify

(* (1/(8 Sqrt[2]))(-I π + 2 Sqrt[2] Log[Cos[x/2] - Sin[x/2]] - 
  2 Sqrt[2] Log[Cos[x/2] + Sin[x/2]] + 2 Log[Sqrt[2] + 2 Sin[x]] - 
  Log[2 - Sqrt[2] Cos[x] - Sqrt[2] Sin[x]] - 
  Log[2 + Sqrt[2] Cos[x] - Sqrt[2] Sin[x]]) *)
```

`expr1` is **an** antiderivative of `expr0`

```
expr0 == D[expr1, x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

expr2 = (1/8) Log[Sin[x] - 1] + (1/4) Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[
     Sin[x] Sqrt[2]] - (1/8) Log[1 + Sin[x]];
```

`expr2` is also ** an ** antiderivative of `expr0`

```
expr0 == D[expr2, x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Antiderivatives can differ by an arbitrary numeric constant (perhaps complex)

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
  Series[expr1 - expr2 // FullSimplify, {x, 0, 10}] // Simplify] // Normal

(* -(1/16) I (2 + Sqrt[2]) π *)
```

As expected, they differ by a numeric constant.

Answer (score 1):

The Rubi package for Mathematica (available at http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) often gives antiderivatives in a nicer form:

```
Int[Sin[x] Csc[4 x], x]
```

> $\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} \sin (x)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{4} \tanh ^{-1}(\sin
>    (x))$

Comment: This is in fact printed in 13.0.1 even without Rubi. Nice.