# How to display detailed output in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a “step by step” evaluation in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148/get-a-step-by-step-evaluation-in-mathematica)
>   [How does Mathematica integrate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6811/how-does-mathematica-integrate)

I want to display more detailed output from a calculation. The default command for calculation that I know is Shift + Enter. Is there another command to display detailed output.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Could you make a specific, concrete example ?

Comment: What is the calculation?

Comment: I updated the post. Now I only get the final result.

Comment: In jest I would propose you use `$Post = Row[{"Much more detailed: ", #}] &` which will now have for instance `2+3` output: `Much more detailed: 5`. However i think you should provide a much more *detailed* definition of what you want when you say "detailed".

Comment: How do you get the result when you type in the mathematical task?

Comment: Are you asking for a "step-by-step" solution like Wolfram Alpha provides?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Comment: Maybe using `Trace` ?

Comment: Yes! This is the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/131 / http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6811/131