# Integrate[] does not work when the function has an antiderivative function

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

This function

```
(1 + (1 + 1/(2*Sqrt[x]))/(2*Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]))/(2*Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]])
```

has the antiderivative function, since

```
D[Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x + Sqrt[x]]], x]== (1 + (1 + 1/(2*Sqrt[x]))/(2*Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]))/(2*Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]])
```

However, when I integrate it in Mathematica, I can't get the result as expected:

```
Integrate[(1 + (1 + 1/(2*Sqrt[x]))/(2*Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]))/(2*
Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]]), x, Assumptions :> x > 0]
```

Why didn't `Integrate[]` function work? I already tried many functions like `Apart[]`, `FullSimplify[]`, `ExpandAll[]`, they didn't work either.

Comment: You may be interested in this answer and the comments there http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6812/193

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question (hence the community tag) since I do not know why Integrate does not solve this, but to point out that the command `Int` solves this instantly with no problem. This is using Albert Rich [Rubi](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) package:

```
ShowSteps = False;
Int[(1 + (1 + 1/(2*Sqrt[x]))/(2*Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]))/(2*Sqrt[x + Sqrt[Sqrt[x] + x]]), x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]